# How to deal with multiple STORES in Pig-Latin Script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a pig script with input like this :

| Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D | Col E |

I have relations like these grouping by various columns:

X = Col A | Sum Col C | Sum Col D|

Y = Col B | Sum Col D | Sum Col E|

Z = ...

ETC

I need to then store X, Y, Z into different folders and thus would be calling STORE multiple times. Does Pig know how to load and process the data only once and then do the stores?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Pig knows how.  You will just have one MR job.

Answer (score 0):

Your input will only be loaded once, but each `GROUP BY` will require a separate MapReduce Job.

In your example you are grouping by `Col A` and `Col B` so your script will compile down to two jobs.

Comment: Pig will combine these map-reduce tasks into a single Hadoop job.

Comment: No - his example has several relations grouped by different columns - to it will be more than one job.

Comment: Pig will combine these map-reduce tasks into a single Hadoop job. This is called multi-query. See the section called "Non-Linear Data Flows" at http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/advanced_pig_latin.html.  Note the sentence "Pig can also combine multiple group operators together in many cases."  This is exactly one of those cases.

Comment: I don't agree. Running a script based on original question results in 2 MR jobs using Pig 0.9.2

Comment: Are you running a script or typing the commands into the Grunt shell?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the specific pig code you have (e.g. can you do one of the joins as skewed etc.)
In any event pig has the `EXPLAIN` keyword which shows you the logical plan, the physical plan and, what's relevant here, the map/reduce plan that will be carried to create any relationship. see [Pig's manual](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/test.html#EXPLAIN) for more details